# HTML email table buttons

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-table, width

I have been trying to update our email from using a bunch of images to just code but I'm hitting an issue with using tables. I can't seem to get the 's to be as narrow as I need them to be. All I want is to have them be fairly close to each other and aligned left. I've never worked with tables before, but I read up on them and everything seems to be correct but nothings working. Any suggestions on what I need to edit? PS This will be seen a lot on Outlook so that is a big factor.

http://codepen.io/Mdadedesign/pen/qavwkg

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<tr style='mso-yfti-irow:4;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes; background-color:pink; width:300px'>


          <td width="90" style="background-color:lightblue;">
            <table width="90" style="float:left;">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" bgcolor="#075aa0" width="90" style="-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 5px;width: 90px;display: block;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 11.5px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid red;line-height:15px;">
                              <a href="http://premierdisability.com/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">
                                Android App
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>


          <td width="70" style="background-color:cornsilk;">
            <table width="70" style="float:left;">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#075aa0" width="70" style="-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 5px;width: 90px;display: block;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 11.5px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid red;line-height:15px;">
                              <a href="http://premierdisability.com/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">
                                Apple App
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>


          <td width="70" style="background-color:lightblue;">
            <table width="70" style="float:left;">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" bgcolor="#075aa0" width="90" style="-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 5px;width: 90px;display: block;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 11.5px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid red;line-height:15px;">
                              <a href="http://premierdisability.com/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">
                                Refer A Friend
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>


                  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the three buttons at the bottom, the "Android App", "Apple App" and "Refer a friend", right?

If you look at the styles you have, you have both a width set on the table, and a width in px set in the style for each button. Not that much to be done with the total width, really, but you can change the first one from 90px to 70px, the second one from 90px to 60px, and the last one from 90px to 80px. If you want to make them smaller than that, you'll have to put them under eachother, or reduce the size of the text and the clickable area.

Comment: Yes I am talking about those three buttons. But the size of the buttons will mostly stay the same. The only part I'm worried about is the space between them. As highlighted with the alternating lightly colored backgrounds. So are <tr>'s not able to be shorter than the <table>? Or is that just cause of the styling?

Comment: Aha. I'm sorry, I misunderstood a bit what you were asking. That would be solved by using `border-collapse: collapse;`on each `<table>`-element within the buttons. So for each `<table>`you either add the above, or add `style="border-collapse: collapse;"` if not style is already assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply JFJ. I just tried that out and it helped a bit but all it really did was remove a small amount of space on all sides of the cell. So now it's flush on the top, left and bottom but that space to the right is still there. I updated the Code Pen that I linked to earlier. I even added the collapse to all elements on the "Refer A Friend" just to see if that might do the trick also.